# How to pass Redux store into a component created by React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, createelement

I have a component defined as

```
    class _MyComponent extends React.Component{
          render() {
            return (
                ...
            );
          }
    }

    const MyComponent= connect(
              store => {
                    return {
                        ...
                    };
                  }
                )(_MyComponent);
    export default MyComponent;
```

Now I want to insert it into a container (a div with id="container")

```
ReactDOM.render(<div>{React.createElement(MyComponent)}</div>, document.getElementById("container"))
```

I got

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(_MyComponent)".
```

How can I pass the Redux store into the component "MyComponent"?

thanks

coolshare

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Provider that delivers the store via context. That is basically what the Error message is telling you.

Take a look at the documentation: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#vanilla-react

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyRootComponent />
  </Provider>,
  rootEl
)
```

So all you have to do is wrap MyComponent with the Provider. The Provider needs the store. It is also your responsibility to create that store. 
http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#example

Answer (score 0):

The standard way as per the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) is by wrapping `_MyComponent` inside a `Provider` like this:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const store = createStore(/* reducers here */);

// .._MyComponent definition

// Render to the DOM
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <_MyComponent />
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById("container"))
```

You can then access the store by using the `connect` method from `react-redux`.

Comment: can you give an example of a component how it uses connect to access the store and get data

Comment: How you deal with this? any idea ?